# valgrind memory lost in array of pointes

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am using Valgrind to debug my c program.
The error I receive is:

```
==2765== 8,000 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==2765==    at 0x4C274A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==2765==    by 0x404123: main (mycode.cpp:352)
```

Here is the code near line 352:

```
int **matrix;
matrix = (int**)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int)); //line 352
}
for (i=0; i<2; i++){ //inizialization
    for (k=0; k<size; k++)
        matrix[i][k] = 0;
}
```

That is my way to allocate memory for a matrix. 
What is wrong with this?

---

Update:
At the end of the program, I used:

```
free(matrix);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  The error is in the code that frees `matrix`.  Can you update your question to show this too please?

Comment: I think I've said it before, but I'll say it again: [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: I updated the question as simonc asked. Thanks unwind :), I will read your post carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valgrind output suggests that you are freeing `matrix` but not its members.  You must have one call to `free` for each allocation:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    free(matrix[i]);
}
free(matrix);
```

Note that you could simplify your code, avoiding the initialise to zero loops, if you allocated memory using `calloc`:

```
int **matrix = malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    matrix[i] = calloc(size*sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you people all insist on allocating each row of an array separately? Just make one large alloc and a getter/setter method!

```
#define ARR_COLUMNS 10
#define ARR_ROWS 10

int* arr = calloc (ARR_COLUMNS * ARR_ROWS, sizeof(int));

int get(int* arr, int x, int y) {
  if (x<0 || x>= ARR_COLUMNS) return 0;
  if (y<0 || y>= ARR_ROWS) return 0;
  return arr[ARR_COLUMNS*y+x];
}

void set (int* arr, int x, int y, int val) {
  if (x<0 || x>= ARR_COLUMNS) return;
  if (y<0 || y>= ARR_ROWS) return;
  arr[ARR_COLUMNS*y+x] = val;
}
```

By doing so you will:

- save yourself costly allocs and frees
- have less fragmented memory
- simplify your possible realloc calls
- ensure the data is cached better and accessed without the common [x][y] vs [y][x] iteration cache problem.

Comment: Great! But I was wondering if it works also if I have to increase both the number of rows and column.

Comment: For 2D array reallocation you would have to write your own function that would `memmove` chunks of the array after realloc into their new places and zero the "new" part of the array. It is fairly simple, though must be done with care.

Answer (score 1):

Like simonc says, it sounds like you're not freeing the individual array elements.

If you're using a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays, you can simplify things a bit and use a single `malloc` and `free` call like so:

```
int size;
...
int (*matrix)[size] = malloc(2 * sizeof *matrix);
...
// do stuff with matrix[i][j]
...
free (matrix);
```

If you're using a compiler that doesn't support VLAs, you'll either have to do the two-step allocation and deallocation, or allocate a 1-d array and map indices as in Darius' answer.